# Remove all non alpha characters from a string including &nbsp; &amp; or any & code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, gsub, strip-tags

Given a string like `"Whatup &nbsp; <b>whatever<b> \n"`, i need to turn that into "Whatup whatever".

I'm pretty close with my below method, but I can't find a good way to remove dynamic `&amp;` and `&nbsp;` type codes. I don't want to gsub each out (like i'm doing with the comma) -- There are hundreds of thousands of rows and many different codes in them...blah

Any pointers are welcome.

```
  def self.clean_string(st)
    return strip_tags(st).force_encoding("UTF-8").gsub(",","").squish if st and st != ""
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the HTML entities, add this regex replacement:

```
.gsub(/&[^;]+;/, '')
```

It will remove any `&amp;`-style entity from the text.

Comment: that should work.  i might fork it to find missing semi colon too.  Our data is hosed with markup by ppl who don't write code